# pybabel text extraction from mako templates

Tags: pylons, mako, babeljs

By default pybabel is extacting `${_("mystr")}` strings just fine from my mako templates, but when I try to use `${pgettext("myctx", "mystr")}` for contextual translations, it doesn't seem to find and extract them.

My babel config is pretty basic:

```
[mako: templates/**.mako]
encoding = utf-8
```

Does anyone know how to get pybabel to extract pgettext translations from mako templates?

Answer (score 0):

With Flask I implemented it importing pgettext for Mako:

kw['imports'] = ['from flask.ext.babel import gettext as _, pgettext']